# save picture to movieclip / sending sum picture at once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file-upload, editor, image-editor

i have this apps: http://www.jungle-g.co.il/#/System/

Currently, when a user selects a product (eg shirt) He can make only one side of the shirt.
 When the user wants to edit another side of the shirt, he will have to complete the booking of the first side and then invite the other side.

My problem is I can not find how to save the first image in the flash memory or in movieclipe.
 My interview is to create a movieclip one for each side user edits only when the user decides to do the actual booking send all the pictures from the movieclip.
 Is this possible? If not is there another way?

I did research on the topic and found no solution that I could use it.
 I found the website: http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/
 But I did not understand how it helps me in my case.

Thank you to all the helpers, I break my head for over a month on the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to hold statics of your bitmapData.

```
package {

    public class ShirtState
    {
        public static var ShirtFront:BitmapData;
        public static var ShirtBack:BitmapData;
    }
}
```

Say you have a shirt that you're editing one side of.

```
 var shirtFront:MovieClip; //this is the shirt you are working with.
```

once you are done

```
 var shirtFrontBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(shirtFront.width, shirtFront.height);
 shirtFrontBitmap.draw(shirtFront);
```

once you have the bitmap you can save it to your static class

```
 ShirtState.shirtFront = shirtFrontBitmap.bitmapData;
```

you can then access it anytime in your app provided you don't reload it.

There are some caveats:

If you have a module application where individual swfs are loaded and unloaded by the DOM then you may want to use a LocalSharedObject to store your images. To do that you will have to convert the bitmap data to Base64 (I would anyways) and then store taht string in the local share object. Be mindful that object has a max file size (not sure what it is).

You don't necessarily have to store bitmaps of your shirt sides. You could create your application to create a Class for shirt and as long as an instance of it exists you can have access to both sides of the shirt.

I am not sure how you are building this app, but generally you wouldn't even need to use a static if everything is in the same context. The actual service call to deliver both sides of the shirt to a server for processing would be made at the absolute end.

Comment: It really helped me,
 From here I continue to try some other things